# How to access HttpContext and Request in RequireAssersion?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, security

I'm trying to create a custom authorization policy. Let's say I want the URL to contain a token. For example:

```
https://example.com/customer/list?token=2nHxltsDOjThQJWufcGU1v36RdqYoBE9
```

I want to show the list of customer to the user, only if:

1. URL has a token query string
2. token is valid

I tried this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsPaydar", policy => policy.RequireAssertion(x => // stuck here))
});
```

But I don't see how can I access HttpContext or the Request object from inside the `policy.RequireAssertion`.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

Since the question was specifically about `RequireAssertion`, which takes a Func, which receives an `AuthorizationHandlerContext`, the answer is that the HttpContext is the AuthorizationHandlerContext’s Resource. To use OP’s code:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsPaydar", policy
        => policy.RequireAssertion(x => (x.Resource as HttpContext)?.Request?.Query["token"] == "myCoolToken")
});
```

Whether the Resource property really contains the HttpContext is up to the framework, so Zhi Lv’s solution is certainly going to be more robust and you should probably use it anyway if your validation logic exceeds one line.

Comment: What do you mean *is up to the framework*?

Comment: @AliEXE [That’s what the docs say](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0#access-mvc-request-context-in-handlers)  Prior to ASP.NET Core 5 the Resource property contains an Endpoint. The property is typed nullable object, so a framework update could theoretically put something else in there without breaking the API.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Authorization Handler, and in this handler get the token parameter from the Query string, and valid the joken. Refer the following steps:

1. Create a JwtTokenRequirement class: here we can set the query string parameter key value. then in the handler method, we could according to it to find the token.

   ```
    //required using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    public class JwtTokenRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
    {
        public JwtTokenRequirement(string  tokenname)
        {
            TokenName = tokenname;
        }

        public string TokenName { get; set; }
    }
   ```
2. Create the JWTTokenHandler:

   ```
    //required using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
    //required using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
    public class JWTTokenHandler : AuthorizationHandler<JwtTokenRequirement>
    {
        IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor = null;

        public JWTTokenHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
        {
            _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        }
        protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, JwtTokenRequirement requirement)
        {

            HttpContext httpContext = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext; // Access context here

            var token =  httpContext.Request.Query[requirement.TokenName].ToString();  //get the jwtkoken

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
            {
                if (IsValidToken(token))
                {
                    context.Succeed(requirement);

                }

            }
            else
            {
                context.Fail();
            } 
            return Task.FromResult(0);
        }

        public bool IsValidToken(string authToken)
        {
            //validate Token here  
            return true;
        }
    }
   ```
3. Add the following code to the ConfigureServices method:

   ```
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("jwtpolicy",
                              policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new JwtTokenRequirement("jwttoken"))); //configure the policy and set the parameter key value. in this sample the key is "jwttoken"
        });
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, JWTTokenHandler>();
   ```
4. Apply the Authorize attribute on the API action method:

   ```
    [Authorize(Policy = "jwtpolicy")]
    [HttpGet("{id}")] 
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }
   ```

Then the result is like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach I used is this:

- The main problem here is that the `AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource` property returns a `RouteEndpoint` object which does not expose the current `HttpContext`.

  - In ASP.NET Core 5, the `.Resource` property now returns the `HttpContext`, but in my case I'm currently stuck on ASP.NET Core 3.1.
- The `AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource` property value comes from the `Object resource` parameter argument passed into `IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync(ClaimsPrincipal user, object resource, IEnumerable<IAuthorizationRequirement> requirements)`

  - So a solution exists by instead passing the current `HttpContext` as the argument for the `resource` parameter - or better-yet: passing a custom object that contains both the `HttpContext` and the `RouteEndpoint`.
  - And this can be done by subclassing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator` and overriding `IPolicyEvaluator.AuthorizeAsync(AuthorizationPolicy policy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext context, object resource);` such that the `HttpContext context` (and `object resource`) objects are passed down into `IAuthorizationService.AuthorizeAsync`.

Like so:

```cs
public class MyPolicyEvaluator : PolicyEvaluator
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationService authorizationService;
    private readonly AuthorizationOptions authorizationOptions;

    public MyPolicyEvaluator( IAuthorizationService authorizationService, IOptions<AuthorizationOptions> authorizationOptions )
        : base( authorizationService )
    {
        this.authorizationService = authorizationService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(authorizationService));
        this.authorizationOptions = authorizationOptions.Value;
    }

    public override async Task<PolicyAuthorizationResult> AuthorizeAsync( AuthorizationPolicy effectivePolicy, AuthenticateResult authenticationResult, HttpContext httpContext, Object? resource )
    {
        if( resource is RouteEndpoint ep )
        {
            resource = new MyAuthorizeResourceHack( context, ep );
        }

        AuthorizationResult newAuthenticationResult = await this.authorizationService.AuthorizeAsync( user: context.User, resource: resource, policy: policy ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if( newAuthenticationResult.Succeeded )
        {
            return PolicyAuthorizationResult.Success();
        }

        return authenticationResult.Succeeded ? PolicyAuthorizationResult.Forbid() : PolicyAuthorizationResult.Challenge();
    }
}

public sealed class MyAuthorizeResourceHack
{
    public MyAuthorizeResourceHack( HttpContext httpContext, RouteEndpoint routeEndpoint )
    {
        this.HttpContext   = httpContext   ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( httpContext ) );
        this.RouteEndpoint = routeEndpoint ?? throw new ArgumentNullException( nameof( routeEndpoint ) );
    }

    public HttpContext   HttpContext   { get; }
    public RouteEndpoint RouteEndpoint { get; }
}
```

You'll need to register `MyPolicyEvaluator` in `ConfigureServices` like so:

```cs
void ConfigureServices( IServiceCollection services )
{
    // ...

    _ = services.Replace( ServiceDescriptor.Transient<IPolicyEvaluator, MyPolicyEvaluator>() );

    // ...
}
```

Then inside your Policy/Requirement methods (which are presumably `static` and only have access to `AuthorizationHandlerContext` you'll now be able to do this:

```
public static void ConfigureAuthorizationPolicies( AuthorizationOptions opts )
{
    opts.AddPolicy( "MyPolicy", p => p.RequireAssertion( MyAssertion ) )
}

private static Boolean MyAssertion( AuthorizationHandlerContext ctx )
{
    if( ctx.Resource is MyAuthorizeResourceHack hack )
    {
        HttpContext httpContext = hack.HttpContext;
        // do stuff with HttpContext here
    }
    else
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException( "Expected AuthorizationHandlerContext.Resource to be " + nameof(MyAuthorizeResourceHack) + " but encountered " + ( ctx.Resource?.GetType().FullName ?? "null" ) );
    }
}
```